# Get highest value per unique key in object array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like so:

```
const data = [
    { depth: 0, length: 5 },
    { depth: 1, length: 8 },
    { depth: 1, length: 11 },
    { depth: 1, length: 6 },
    { depth: 1, length: 8 },
    { depth: 1, length: 11 },
    { depth: 1, length: 6 },
    { depth: 1, length: 8 },
    { depth: 2, length: 16 },
    { depth: 2, length: 25 }
];
```

I need to get the highest `length` value per `depth` key. The array I want is:

```
const result = [
    { depth: 0, length: 5 },
    { depth: 1, length: 11 },
    { depth: 2, length: 25 }
];
```

The `data` array can be X depths deep. Other examples I have seen only get the highest value, or single object with the highest value, whereas I need the highest value per key.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through nested objects in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230748/how-to-iterate-through-nested-objects-in-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the array to a Map using the `depth` as key. If the current object doesn't exist in the Map, or the current `length` is the Map is less then the current item's `length`, store the item for that `depth`. Convert to an array by spreading the Map's value iterator:

```js
const data = [{"depth":0,"length":5},{"depth":1,"length":8},{"depth":1,"length":11},{"depth":1,"length":6},{"depth":1,"length":8},{"depth":1,"length":11},{"depth":1,"length":6},{"depth":1,"length":8},{"depth":2,"length":16},{"depth":2,"length":25}];

const result = [...data.reduce((r, o) =>
  (!r.has(o.depth) || r.get(o.depth).length < o.length) ? r.set(o.depth, o) : r
, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed